# AzureAD 2.0.2.180 not authenticating

Tags: azure-active-directory

These are the commands I am running:

[String]$UPN = WHOAMI /UPN
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $UPN -Confirm:$False > $null

When running the above commands with AzureAD module version 2.0.2.140 it works fine and has worked for every member of the company I am in. Now AzureAD has updated to 2.0.2.180 this errors with the following error. Can anyone offer any advice.

ERROR:

Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.

At C:\Users**********\Internal IT - Deployment\Microsoft Intune\Applications\Windows\Outlook Signature\4.2\Application\SupportFiles\OutlookSignature-AAD.ps1:336 char:5

- ```
  Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $UPN -Confirm:$False > $null
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AggregateException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

Connect-AzureAD : There was an error parsing WS-Trust response from the endpoint. This may occur if there is an issue with your ADFS configuration. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa-troubleshooting for more details. Error Message: Federated

service at https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/**********/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=0a1652b0-fbf2-4aa6-a18d-95b20527d1ec returned error: Authentication Failure

At C:\Users**********\Internal IT - Deployment\Microsoft Intune\Applications\Windows\Outlook Signature\4.2\Application\SupportFiles\OutlookSignature-AAD.ps1:336 char:5

- ```
  Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $UPN -Confirm:$False > $null
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], MsalClientException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

Connect-AzureAD : Federated service at https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/**********/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=0a1652b0-fbf2-4aa6-a18d-95b20527d1ec returned error: Authentication Failure

At C:\Users**********\Internal IT - Deployment\Microsoft Intune\Applications\Windows\Outlook Signature\4.2\Application\SupportFiles\OutlookSignature-AAD.ps1:336 char:5

- ```
  Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $UPN -Confirm:$False > $null
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], MsalServiceException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

The normal expectation is that this will authenticate with AzureAD however this is not the case. I have tested rolling back to version 2.0.2.140 and it works again.

Comment: Note that there are 2 separate commands: [String]$UPN = WHOAMI /UPN

Comment: Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $UPN -Confirm:$False > $null

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be msal error .
This occurs when credentials are wrong or probably not given the password.

As the error present: `returned error: Authentication Failure.`

For the new updated version , one need to login with correct credentials first.
So check if in any case wrong credentials are typed and login was interrupted due to network issues.

Also to confirm that correct inputs are given.
For that following commands can be used.

```
$tenantID = "xxxxxxxxxx"
$securefile = "C:\Azure-AD\Password.txt";
#$secureuser = "C:\Azure-AD\UserName.txt";
$username = "xfvd@microsoft.com"
$password = "dfddv" |  ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$MyCredential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password);
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantID -credential $MyCredential
```

[image]

With which the user can be logged in successfully.
Also make sure the dependent libraries are updated.

To update all installed modules to the newest version in an online gallery
Run **`Update-Module`**

[image]

Note: Make sure the updated powershell module exists for all dependent modules.

See [How to Update PowerShellGet  | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/overview?view=powershell-7.3)